# Sentimental Analysis using Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, sentiment-analysis

I am working on problem solution where I am collecting social feeds from twitter and Facebook for a product X . I am labeling these posts,comments or tweets using five labels

```
--Positive
--Negative
--Campaign 
--Reply
--Queries
```

I have a training set of around 5000 which includes tweets,Facebook posts and Comments . But these training set are unbalanced and have more of Negatives and Campaign data . Below is the list of sentiments and their count:

```
--Positive--> 492
--Negative--> 2193
--Campaign--> 1422
--Reply--> 430
--Queries--> 922
```

I am using Naive Bayes for predicting these sentiments . As you can see the above training set is high unbalanced is there any way that I can improve my model with these training set . Any suggestion for improving my prediction model would be helpful .

I am using Mahout for these building this prediction model .

Thank you